# Way to set date automatically from command line

Tags: macos, shell, command-line

I make a script in a command line, but I have a problem. I need change date automatically from a command line. Is it possible?

I know, I can use static date for example:

```
date 0101122315
```

but I need an automatic date from the internet in macOs.

Comment: Why would you do that? Macs keep their time correct already.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got some research to do, here is one possible outline:

1. Use `curl` to have the date from the internet and store in a file or send to standard output - in the latter case you may pipe into more commands or store in a shell variable.
2. If needed: Use `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, *some JSON editor*, etc. to extract the date from the result of (1). Not needed if your URL just returns the date and nothing else.
3. Use `date` and shell variable or command output substitution to pass your date as an argument.

You can find documentation on all the commands, and the shell, using the `man` command, e.g. `man curl`.

You might end up with a short one line script (something like:

```
date `curl URL | sed command`
```

) or something longer. Nobody can really tell you as it is unstated in the question what the URL will return.

If you get stuck once you're further along ask a new question showing what you've developed and explains the error and someone will undoubtedly help you progress.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
    sudo sntp -sS time.apple.com
```